# Converting a published Google Sheet into an RSS Feed

Tags: rss, google-sheets

Quite simply, is there a way to turn [this data](http://bit.ly/arabicnews) into an RSS feed?

*The data set contains yesterday's Arabic news from several sources. Therefore all data will change after midnight in London.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [Kimono](https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/rss/2aoha90s?apikey=uxfRzKZ9Wlf0emdCMJceeq5TNKI2XHQo). [Here is the API](https://www.kimonolabs.com/apis/2aoha90s#data) (login probably required). You can clone the API and make it better.